# Rearranging a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String of the form "Firstname MiddleInitial Lastname".

I want to convert it to "Lastname, Firstname MiddleIntial"

Some names may have middle initial, but some may not:

```
String Name1 = "John Papa P";
String name2 = "Michael Jackson";

// Desired Output
result1 = "Papa, John P";
result2 = "Jackson, Michael";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Maybe `split()` the string, then access the individual words and reassemble them in the form you like it.

Comment: Or even lastIndexOf() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String name1 = "John Papa P";
        String name2 = "Michael Jackson";

        String[] split = name1.split(" ");

        String result;
        if (split.length > 2) {
            result = split[1] + ", " + split[0] + " " + split[2];
        } else {
            result = split[1] + ", " + split[0];
        }

        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method on your String to split it into an array of Strings using a space as a delimiter, and rearrange the array as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this is using split function and make it into lists.

```
    String one = "John Doe";
    String two = "Albert Einstein";
    String [] onelst = one.split(" ");
    String [] twolst = two.split(" ");
    String oneMod = onelst[1]+" "+onelst[0];
    String twoMod = twolst[1]+" "+twolst[0];
    System.out.println(oneMod);
    System.out.println(twoMod);
```

Output for this:

```
Doe John
Einstein Albert
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `split()` to create an array of names. Now just use `size()` to get the size of the array, if it's 3 you have MiddleInitial, if 2 you dont.

Then for each case rearrange the array as you want.